# Show Hide Class based on Time (hours & minutes)

Tags: javascript

I want to make code function is show class and hide class based on hours and minutes

Here's my code

```js
//gets the current time. 
var d = new Date();
var da = d.getHours() + "" + d.getMinutes()
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = da;

if (da.between(d.getHours() + "" + d.getMinutes() >= 730 && d.getHours() + "" + d.getMinutes() <= 1145)) {
  $(".open").show();
  $(".closed").hide();
} else {
  $(".closed").show();
  $(".open").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="display"></div>
<div class="open">We Now Open</div>
<div class="closed">We are Closed</div>
```

I dont know what wrong, but the result all class shown... like this 
https://jsfiddle.net/gwmLrtuy/

Comment: You should probably do something about the error ~ _"Uncaught TypeError: da.between is not a function"_. Why would you expect a string to have a `between` function?

Comment: Here's what I think you wanted ~ https://jsfiddle.net/f1m027n9/. FYI, I had to add jQuery to the fiddle too

Answer (score 0):

Hi try use with script

```js
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();
var mintues = now.getMinutes();


if ( hour*60 >= (9*60+30) && hour*60 <= (18*60+30) ) { 
    $('.open').show();
    $('.closed').hide();
} else {
 $('.open').hide();
  $('.closed').show();
}
```